# In eclipse, how do I select vertically continuous boxes of text, as I would using alt+drag in Notepad++?

Tags: eclipse, notepad++

There is a wonderful feature of notepad++ that allows you to select text by contiguous columns. It is incredibly useful and has the potential to save hours when working on large datasets.

Is there such a feature in Eclipse? I'm not sure of the vocabulary, so I don't know what to search for if it is a Eclipse plugin that does the same work.

This is an Eclipse question, but I have tagged in with notepad++ as well in case someone from that camp who is familiar with the feature of notepad++ knows the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my Eclipse (Helios) "Alt+Shift+A" works. It is being labelled as "Toggle Block Selection Mode".
[image]

Comment: yep. that's the way! it's a bit clunky but works and saves lives!